# javascript で文字列型以外からの map を利用したい

Tags: javascript, node.js

javascript では、 string => any なデータ構造は、ただのオブジェクト自身でそれを表すことが一般的かと思います。

```js
const strMap = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
};

console.log(strMap["foo"]); // => 1
```

今、そうではなく、任意のデータ型をキーとした、 map 構造を取り扱いたいと思いました。

```
// こんなことがやりたい
const someMap = {
  何かしらのオブジェクト1: 値１,
  何かしらのオブジェクト2: 値２
};

someMap.get(何かしらのオブジェクト1);  // 値1 を取得できる
```

#### 質問

- javascript において、 string 以外をキーとしたマップデータ構造には、一般的に何が利用されますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

任意のデータ型をキーとする場合、 Map を使用することが出来ます。

```js
const yama = {name: "yama"};
const tuki = {name: "tuki"};
const a = Symbol(1);

const objMap = new Map([
    [yama, "kawa"],
    [tuki, "suppon"],
    [1, "一"],
    ["1", "2"],
    [a, "syma"],
]);

console.log(objMap.get(yama)); // => kawa
console.log(objMap.get(tuki)); // => suppon
console.log(objMap.get(1)); // => 一
console.log(objMap.get("1")); // => World
console.log(objMap.get(a)); // => syma
```